# Why does f = g = h = [] set the lists equal forever?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Why does

```
f = g = h = []
f.append(1)
```

make

```
f = [1], g=[1], h=[1]
```

?

Why are the lists linked like this? If I would have done the same with integer variables, they would not be linked.

Comment: they *are* linked when you do it with anything and everything (in the first style of writing it)

Comment: That' because `f`,`g`,`h` point to `[]`. When you mutate any of the variables in-place then changes are reflected in all of the variables. And `int` is **immutable** datatype. So, once you mutate the value it points to different object.

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: You can't mutate integer values. `f.append(1)` and `f = 2` are two *completely* different operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` creates a list at a particular location.

Then, you point `f` at that location.

Then, you point `g` at that location as well. And `h`.

It follow naturally that, when you modify that list in-place (without changing its reference), everything pointed at it will see the change.

---

You say that changing an integer won't have this effect. That's because it's a different type of change. Integers in python are immutable, and cannot usually be changed in-place - rather, a new integer must be created (a new reference along with it) and then assigned to the name that was looking at the old one:

```
h = 5
id(h)
# 4318792464
h = 6
id(h)
# 4318792496
# note that these two addresses are different, meaning different locations.
```

if this means the old value is lost forever, then the garbage collector will eventually clean it up and free the memory it was occupying.

As you can see, modifying a list in-place doesn't change its reference:

```
f = g = []
id(f) == id(g)
# True
g.append(1)
id(f) == id(g)
# still True

g = [1]  # make a new list at a different location, with the same value
f == g
# True
id(f) == id(g)
# False
```

Comment: This is as much a FAQ as anything. See the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, particularly the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: You got the order wrong, `f` gets assigned first, not `h`.